# Gradle dependencies groovy closure syntax

Tags: android, groovy, gradle, build.gradle

Very basic question.

This snapshot in `build.gradle` :

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.2'
}
```

is supposed to call method `dependencies(Closure c)` and pass it a closure.

Could someone please explain the syntax of this simple closure 
`{ classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.2' }`

It is not returning anything, is it ?

Comment: It's the same as `project.dependencies({classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.2'})` and according to docs: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html it isn't returning anything. Is that what You were asking about?

Comment: How can I find where `classpath` method is defined ?

Comment: To be honest not even sure if this is a method.

Comment: @Opal what is it then ?

Comment: It might be just a map key like in `apply plugin: 'java'`. Then this key is taken with value and according to it appropriate configuration resolver is called.

Comment: @Opal I am a newby in groovy but I would never believe they designed map & method invokation syntax to be the same. Map probably includes colon, like in your example, no ? So, I think it IS a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures+-+Formal+Definition

Notably:

> **Closures always return a value.** This may occur via either an explicit return statement, or as the value of the last statement in the closure body (e.g. an explicit return statement is optional).

There's not really any syntax to explain; there's a closure, inside it the `classpath` method is called, and it takes a string argument. Whether or not anything is *done* with the return value, or whether or not the return value is *significant*, is a separate issue.

In this case it's not; there's a side-effect of setting the classpath value.

Comment: upvote for the explanations. I did not recognize `classpath` was a method invocation. Does groovy allow to call methods with varargs without parens ? i.e. classpath 'param1' 'param2'

Comment: Calling methods without parens is valid in groovy.

Comment: @kiruwka Without parens, sure. Without commas, no.

Comment: super. Last question. How can I lookup method definitions in groovy/gradle ? When I follow links in my IDE on `classpath` it takes me to method `Dependency add(String configurationName, Object dependencyNotation, Closure configureClosure);` in `DependencyHander` interface. Why the name of the methods / signatures don't match ?

Comment: @kiruwka I usually just grep/ack through source; it's almost always quicker--same as I do in Ruby and JS. Since it's so dynamic methods can pop up from just about anywhere.

Comment: accepted. Could you please answer my comment after the question regarding map/method difference. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @kiruwka It could be handled in a variety of ways, e.g., a method missing handler that delegates to something, etc. I can't poke around right now, but breaking on `Dependency#add` might provide some clues, e.g., if `configurationName` is `classpath` that's probably a strong hint.